# Creating switch statement gives me error

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have an `enum` with 4 objects inside. I then passed one to a `variable`. I'm trying to create a `switch statement` to see which object was passed. Here is my code:

```
enum Collection:Int{
        case First=1, Second, Third, Fourth
}
var myCollection : Collection!

// Later on...
myCollection = Collection.Second

// Later on...
switch self.myCollection {
    case .Second:
    println("Second")
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Enum case 'Second' not found in type 'myViewController.Collection!'

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try resolving the scope fully. Where have you defined the enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit odd and it seems the error-message is not particularly helpful. The fix nevertheless is one of the below.

1. change `var myCollection : Collection!` to `var myCollection : Collection`.
2. `switch myCollection as Collection` or the short-form `switch myCollection!`

The reason is that implicitly unwrapped `myCollection` is not of the type `Collection` but actually of the type `Collection!`.

Comment: Alternatively cast myCollection to Collection in the switch: `switch myCollection as Collection`

Comment: You should add the last comment to your answer